# Database not displaying in Management Studio but data file present in DATA directory

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

TL;DR Some databases that have data files in my local MSSql Express DATA directory stopped appearing in Management Studio.

I inherited a development environment on my desktop at work which includes an MSSql Express 2008 instance. Now, I know I've probably done something with the config, but for the life of me can't remember having done anything that could have the effect I'm seeing.

I come into work on morning and to a pile of errors from an application saying that it could not connect to its database. When I start Management Studio to check what's up, I can't see the databases listed anymore. Checking the DATA directory, the mdb file, and log file for the databases are all present.

This is on an SQL Server Express 2008 r2 installation on a Windows 7 workstation.

Anyone any ideas what I can do to reinstate the databases? (Yes, I'm a know-nothing when it comes to MSSql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click on "databases" -> "attach..." then choose your *.mdf files and your databases should appear in your studio again.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and got 'Cannot show requested dialog'. Starting to think the problems may go a little deeper.

Comment: If you get that error message after clicking on "attach..." something is not correct with your connection to the SQLDatabase instance.
Try to go on you instance on "disconnect" and connect again. maybe this will help. Otherwise iam not sure whats happening. Maybe you should restart the SQLServer service in your services probably this will help.

Comment: I've tried all the usual before-last-resort things. I'm resigned to advancing to the MS last resort action of simply re-installing SQL Server express. Sure, I had nothing else to do this afternoon. Thanks again.

Comment: Iam sry for not be able to help you :) have a nice evening

Answer (score 2):

This can be an issue with permissions; best to create a folder in any drive except c:\ (say d:\DBFiles).

Right click on the folder --> Properties --> Security --> and give full control.

Run this script.

CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks

```
ON (FILENAME = ' D:\DBFiles\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'), 

(FILENAME = ' D:\DBFiles\AdventureWorks2012_Log.ldf')     FOR ATTACH;
```